# Get First Row Of SQLite Database Using Python

Tags: python, database, sqlite

I want to have a better solution than mine, for getting the first row of an SQLite database using Python.

```
import sqlite3

con = sqlite3.connect('emails.db')
cur = con.cursor()

cur.execute('SELECT * FROM my_table LIMIT 1')
print(cur.fetchall())

con.close()
```

outputs the correct row, but I think `SELECT *` iterates through my entire table, which is inefficient. I tried COUNT(*) but couldn't succeed.

Comment: You should learn a bit more about SQL if you think `count(*)` could have helped you

Comment: Use `fetchone` and remove LIMIT

Comment: Just to note... `SELECT` doesn't refer to rows - it refers to columns... so your approach is fine as the `LIMIT 1` will just take the first row and not bother looking any further.